# TimerCallback - Possible to change time?

Tags: c#, timer

I have this function...

```
Instance(uint InstanceId) { }
```

Inside it is this code...

```
        mUpdater = new Timer(new TimerCallback(PerformUpdate), null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
```

It refreshes PerformUpdate every 500 milliseconds

In PerformUpdate i have a IF statement to calculate if a user has a specfic variable defined. How would I make it so if a user has the variable, then it only refreshes every 300 milliseconds instead of 500.

Oh and it cannot be set inside the Instance function as its a per user command and Instance is for every user.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it's for the `System.Threading.Timer`, not `System.Timers.Timer`, correct?
You can call the `Change` method on a `System.Threading.Timer` to change its start time and interval.

```
var variableDefined = true;        
var threadingCallback = new System.Threading.TimerCallback((o) => { });
var threadingTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(threadingCallback, null, 0, 500);
if (variableDefined) {
    threadingTimer.Change(0, 300);
}
```